# Which groups allow selecting the properties allowExternalSenders or autoSubscribeNewMembers?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I select the properties `allowExternalSenders` or `autoSubscribeNewMembers` for a group synced from an on-premise Active Directory, I get the following error via Graph API SDK:

```
403 Forbidden
Graph service exception Error code: AppOnlyAccessNotEnabledForTarget
Error message: App Only access is not allowed for target resource: 'a1d0c98e-fb7e-40c4-a7b5-ccf6d96cba57@34f0717f-f1a0-4894-b310-d379993504b9'.
```

The Graph Explorer displays the following `404` error, even though it is not a mailbox:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI",
    "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5beae8eb-4a59-404f-bd42-0c6aa2a25abd",
      "date": "2020-03-31T13:02:11"
    }
  }
}
```

An example request looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}?$select=id,deletedDateTime,assignedLicenses,description,displayName,groupTypes,licenseProcessingState,mail,mailEnabled,mailNickname,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,onPremisesDomainName,onPremisesSamAccountName,preferredDataLocation,securityEnabled,securityIdentifier,visibility,resourceProvisioningOptions,allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers
```

Which property should I use to decide if I should try to select these properties or not? I want to avoid missing the properties for groups which actually do expose these properties, so I do not simply want to guess.

Comment: Does this subscription have Exchange Online provisioned? Even though you're requesting a group, you're requesting two properties that rely on Exchange.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is a Exchange hybrid environment. However, as far as I understood it, these two properties are not related to Exchange. Office 365 allows sending mails to some types of groups and these properties control that. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different take on this answer, Microsoft even thought only providing one API for groups, there are effectively two different objects returned, SecurityEnabled = True or False. If Security = True then you can not ask for the follow attributes

> (allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers,hideFromAddressLists,hideFromOutlookClients)

Is this ok, NO its not ok, Microsoft needs to return null instead of providing THE WRONG ERROR MESSAGE and sending people like us into multi hour head scratchers.

In my code, I now check if securityEnabled is true or false and have a different set of attributes depending.

Answer (score 0):

The mailbox is on a dedicated (on premise) Microsoft Exchange Server or is not a valid (configured) Office 365 mailbox. Contact your Exchange or Office admin to apply any of [these recommended solutions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462988/rest-api-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox-error).

To filter Office 365 groups you can do this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified')`

Comment: Thank you, but that much is obvious and does not answer the question. Also, the properties exist for any Office 365 group, which obviously have mail addresses, but do not constitute mailboxes as far is I know.

The question is: When I load a group using the Graph API, which property or properties tell me if the group also provides the aforementioned attributes?

Comment: @ManuelK apologies for missing the main question. I've updated my answer.